# Git merge auto-add all new lines

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

//EDITED FOR CLARITY

Is there any way to actually, or theoretically merge two commits and keeps all of the different content between them.

Suppose you have a master branch with a single file called index.js

```
//master
//index.js
alert('A');
alert('Z');
```

Two branches off of master look like this:

```
//Branch 1
//index.js
alert('A');
alert('B');
alert('Z');

//Branch 2
//index.js
alert('A');
alert('C');
alert('Z');
```

The ideal automerge result merging Branch 1 to Branch 2 would be

```
//Branch 2
//index.js
alert('A');
alert('B');
alert('C');
alert('Z');
```

Is there anyway this is achievable?

Comment: I believe you _might_ already end up with this after a `git merge`, though it could also have conflicts (with the file having conflict markers).  With regard to the alphabetical order of `alert('B')` showing before `alert('C')`, I don't this is possible.  Assuming you do get a merge conflict, is there any reason why in general you would not to resolve it by hand?

Comment: I'm just trying to streamline the process. For the work that I'm doing, it's a lot of fixes for a lot of small changes. I thought that maybe git would have a tag for including the diff between two files.

Comment: Maybe I'm answering my own question here, but would a possible solution be to use a git wrapper like gitty (for npm), and when I get the diff, checkout into a new branch, run my own script to merge the files, and then throwaway the conflicted branch

Comment: Why would you need to create a new branch?  There is a way to tell Git to automatically complete a merge of a file using the version from one branch or the other.  But in your case, you want to use information from both branches, and you want that done automatically.

Comment: I guess that's essentially the question then

Comment: Try seeing if you find a way to automatically remove merge conflict markers.  This would leave you with a file which is a bona-fide meld of the two branches, according to how Git sees things.  You could create a script to do this, or possibly find a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagrams are confusing, and they don't do justice to the point you are trying to make.  Your basic question is can you *preserve* all the commits in two feature branches such that they appear in your `master` branch whence they were created.  Git has a tool for doing this, and it is called `git rebase`.  Consider the following scenario:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
branch1: A -- B -- D
branch2: A -- B -- E
```

In this example, both `branch1` and `branch2` were branched off `master` at commit `B`, and both have one additional commit since then.  The following command will `rebase` `branch1` on `master`, thereby bringing in the changes from `master` while preserving all commits:

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
```

Now the diagrams will look like this:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
branch1: A -- B -- C -- D'
branch2: A -- B -- E
```

Now `branch1` can be pushed onto `master` using `git push origin branch1:master` leaving the diagrams looking like this:

```
master:  A -- B -- C -- D'
branch1: A -- B -- C -- D'
branch2: A -- B -- E
```

Rebasing can also be done for `branch2` which would leave the diagrams looking like this:

```
master:  A -- B -- C -- D' -- E'
branch1: A -- B -- C -- D'
branch2: A -- B -- C -- D' -- E'
```

Now your `master` branch has all the commits from both branches.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I tried to make the question a little more clear on your feedback.  I feel bad because I think you gave a great answer-- to another question, but it's not really what I was looking for